# I want to close override method in adapter. Is the resolve good practice?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want to improve my `recyclerview` list adapter via binding view model from `fragment` to my `adapter`.

So my new `recyclerview` adapter updates data via subscribe to view model.

Now i need to close submit list `override` fun. Because i don't need to update `adapter` via `fragment`. To update data i use binded view model instead.

My solving is:

```
 @Deprecated("use vm instead", ReplaceWith("throw RuntimeException(\"Calling from fragment is deprecated!\")"))
    override fun submitList(data: MutableList<InvitedGuyVo>?) {
        throw RuntimeException("Calling from fragment is deprecated!")
    }
```

But my doubt is good practice to throw exception if i want to bun override fun?

Comment: Well technically this is a code smell called "Refused Bequest", and generally a sign of violating the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce will think about you comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API does not deny one from calling the method. It may turn out there is a usage of the class via a base class or interface, where they may not see the deprecation.
The `final` keyword may help to deny the method from being re-implemented in the inheritor classes.

You may have a stronger `@Deprecated` annotation in Kotlin with the level set to `HIDDEN`, e.g.

```
@Deprecated("message", level = DeprecationLevel.HIDDEN)
```

The annotation may the method invisible for an IDE, but still visible for the binary code.

The best way to solve the problem, but probably too hard way, could be to create a dedicated hierarchy of classes or interfaces, where there is no way in principle to call the method that you try to hide.